# A problem faced when trying to get all the documents in one collection in FaunaDB using javaScript

Tags: javascript, faunadb

I created database and one collection . Now I want to retrieve all the documents from this collection.

I used this query method :

```
q.Map(
  q.Paginate(Documents(Collection('posts'))),
  q.Lambda(x => q.Get(x))
).then (x=>console.log(x))
```

But every time I run this code, it sends me an error message telling that the Documents is not defined .
Can anybody tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add the error message that you're seeing? I'm thinking that it would be helpful to clarify whether this is a javascript error (`Documents` has not been declared), or something library specific

Comment: Hi .
The error message is :Uncaught ReferenceError: Documents is not defined.

I think I recognize what caused the error . I did't Import all the functions of the FaunaDB when I pasted its CDN in the html file . I tried before to download it in the javascript as a file . But after that when I use require function to bring it in the app file , it said that require is not defined .

Answer (score 1):

You use q. in front of Map, Paginate and Lambda. I assume that means you did not do something as follows

```js
import faunadb from 'faunadb'
const q = faunadb.query
const { Documents, Paginate, Collections, Lambda, Get } = q
```

If you did that, this should work. (Disclaimer: make sure not to overwrite language specific functions like Map and or Function, for these, please use q.Function and q.Map.

The other way would be to put q in front of everything.

```js
q.Map(
  q.Paginate(q.Documents(q.Collection('posts'))),
  q.Lambda(x => q.Get(x))
).then (x=>console.log(x))
```

As mentioned, if you do expose the functions (I find that convenient personally), don't do it with Map since that's a JavaScript keyword, so the best you can get is:

```js
import faunadb from 'faunadb'
const q = faunadb.query
const { Documents, Paginate, Collections, Lambda, Get } = q

q.Map(
  Paginate(Documents(Collection('posts'))),
  Lambda(x => Get(x))
).then (x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Brecht . I followed what you did by adding this : 
```
const { Documents, Paginate, Collections, Lambda, Get } = q 
```
and it worked (: 
But another problem has emerged now , which is : 'q.Map(...).then is not a function'
here I added (.then )  to console the response .
Why is it saying that it's not a function ?

Comment: Now after I use async function and await I got this response (Expr {raw: {…}} ) instead of the documents !

Comment: Could you try to update your node faunadb library? That sounds like a problem with importing multiple faunadb libraries which was fixed recently.